# C# JSON Newtonsoft.JSon to get name

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have following JSon and I am using Json.NET (Newtonsoft.Json):

```
{
  "total_items": "62",
  "page_number": "6",
  "page_size": "10",
  "page_count": "7",
  "cars": {
    "car": [     
      {
        "car_name": "Honda",
        "engines": {
          "engine": [
            {
              "name": "1.2L"
            },
            {
              "name": "1.8L"
            }
          ]
        },
        "country": "Japan"
      },
      {
        "car_name": "Ford",
        "engines": {
          "engine": {
              "name": "2.2L"
          }
        },
        "country": "Japan"
      },
      { 
        "car_name": "VW",
        "engines": null,
        "country": "Germany"      
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I have following Car object:

```
class Car
{
    public Car() { }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public List<String> EngineNames { get; set; }
}
```

I need to handle case if "engines=null".  If it is not null, then get all engine names.  So, for example above, my EngineNames list for Honda and VW would be:

- Honda.EngineNames = {"1.2L", "1.8L"}  // has 2 names
- VW.EngineNames = null //has nothing since no engine is provided

I need to pars the JSON above to get car data.  I am parsing car_name and country but I dont know how to parse all engine names in array of engines (array could be null).

```
private Cars GetCars(string json)
{
    dynamic data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

    foreach (dynamic d in data.cars.car)
    {
        Car c = new Car(); 

        c.Name = (string)d.SelectToken("car_name");
        c.Country = (string)d.SelectToken("country");
        c.EngineNames = //HOW TO GET ALL ENGINE NAMES AND HANDLE NULL ?

        CarList.Add(c);
    }
    return CarList;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The best approach is to cut this dynamic a-la-javascript kind of crap out and just define your strongly typed models that will match your JSON structure:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public Cars Cars { get; set; }
}

public class Cars
{
    public Car[] Car { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "car_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public Engines Engines { get; set; }
}

public class Engines
{
    public Engines()
    {
        Engine = new Engine[0];
    }

    // We need to use a custom JSON converter
    // because of this pretty broken schema that you have
    // in which the engine property can be array and a standard
    // object at the same time
    [JsonConverter(typeof(EnginesConverter))]
    public Engine[] Engine { get; set; }
}

public class Engine
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then just let JSON.NET do the magic of converting this string back into your strongly typed objects:

```
var wrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(json);
```

and now that you have a strongly typed structure, you could more than easily map this to a desired C# DTO using LINQ:

```
public class CarsDto
{
    public CarsDto()
    {
        Engines = new List<string>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public List<string> Engines { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
var dto = wrapper.Cars.Car.Select(c => new CarsDto
{
    Name = c.Name,
    Country = c.Country,
    Engines = (c.Engines ?? new Engines()).Engine.Select(e => e.Name).ToList(),
}).ToList();
```

and finally here's the custom JSON converter that we used:

```
public class EnginesConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize<Engine[]>(reader);
        }
        else
        {
            Engine e = serializer.Deserialize<Engine>(reader);
            return new[] { e };
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: @DarinDimitrow Thanks.  Why is only Name property adorned with JSonProperty?  Sorry, new to this, so need bit of explanation what is happening here.  Thanks

Comment: That's because in your JSON structure this property is called `car_name` whereas in the strongly typed wrapper it's called `Name` - it would have been more than peculiar to have a C# property called `car_name`, wouldn't it? That's why we need to specify to JSON.NET how this specific mapping should take place. Of course if you have named your C# property `public string car_name { get; set; }` then you wouldn't have needed this attribute but, come on, is there a C# developer that has at least a little respect for himself that would ever name a C# property using such convention?

Comment: I prefer to embrace the dynamic nature of JSON, and parse it dynamically inside parser class, that can evolve easily when the JSON does, and encapsulates the parsing details from other classes in the system.

Comment: Then all I can wish you is best of luck in this endeavor.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I just found another issue and updated the JSON above.  Now Honda has 2 engines (so it is an array), VW is null, but ford has 1 engine (so not an array).  Would this still work?

Comment: No, this won't work that way. You have completely broken JSON schema. How is it possible that `engine` is sometimes an array and sometimes a normal object. You could write a custom json converter to handle this scenario. I have updated my answer to illustrate the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Why not continue using dynamic typing, and access object properties as dynamics, so you can do:

```
var car = new Car();

car.Name = (string)d.car_name;
car.EngineNames = (d.engines != null ? ((IEnumerable)d.engines).Cast<dynamic>().Select(e => (string)e.name) : null);
```

Comment: Thanks but that fails to build.  It returns error "Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments"

Comment: @dbnex14 that's because you need to add System.Collections namespace first: using System.Collections;

Comment: that removed the previous error but now it complains at "Select(" part with error "The name 'Select' does not exist in the current context "

Comment: Select is an extension method in System.Linq namespace. Add using System.Linq;

Comment: In the code sample I'm missing a . between Cast<dynamic>() and Select, I assume you have fixed it.

Comment: I added "." like Cast<dynamic>().Select(... but now I get error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: The compiler is right, I forgot EngineNames is IEnumerable<string> so a cast between IEnumerable<dynamic> and IEnumerable<string> is missing, see the updated example.

Comment: I mean that we were assigning an object of type IEnumerable<dynamic> to a property of type IEnumerable<string>. That is not allowed, so first we need to tell the compiler that we know e.name is of type string, so it builds an IEnumerable<string> that can be assigned to EngineNames. See the updated example, I added a cast inside the Select statement.

Comment: Yes, I see that.  I changed to car.EngineNames = (d.engines != null ? ((IEnumerable)d.engines).Cast<dynamic>().Select(e => (string)e.name) : null); but this gives new error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Just use .ToList() after Select or change EngineNames to be IEnumerable<string>....

Comment: Thanks for your help but I discovered another problem.  I updated the JSON in my original post above.  You see that Ford has only one engine and as a result, it is not an array.  So, 3 cases exist: array like for Honda, just 1 engine (so no array) for Ford, and null like in case of VW.  The problem is that  car.EngineNames = (d.engines != null ? ((IEnumerable)d.engines.engine).Cast<dynamic>().Select(e => (string)e.name) : null); will fail on Ford. (NOTE that I added "engine" to "d.engines in code.